# A conformal mapping from a sector to a strip

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, conformal-geometry

What is the simplest function that maps the sector $r < 1$, $0 < \theta < \pi$ conformally onto the strip $0 < u < \pi/2$, $v > 0$? Here, $r$, $\theta$, $u$, $v$ have their usual meaning.